# Convert byte Array into DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, arrays, binaryformatter

I am reading a bin file which contains data in byte format and then converting into DataTable format. But the problem is only one row is being read when the file contains 3 rows.

```
byte[] bytedata = File.ReadAllBytes("Output1.bin");
DataTable data = new DataTable();
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream = new MemoryStream(bytedata);
data = (DataTable)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: I first serialize a 3x3 dataTable with a BinaryFormatter and use your code to deserialize, but can't not repro ...Open "Output1.bin" in a text editor, does it really contain 3 rows?

Comment: Yes it does. I am first writing those rows to the output1.bin file and then trying to read it. But all it does is just reads the first row.

Comment: posting all your code? maybe the content of the datatable matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const int MAX_BUFFER = 2048;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
int BytesRead;
DataTable data = new DataTable();
using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Output1.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
while ((BytesRead = fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != 0)
{
string text = (Convert.ToBase64String(Buffer));
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream = new MemoryStream(Buffer);
data = (DataTable)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
}
```

This is the working code. It reads all data from file in filestream and then to `ByteArray` and finally to DataTable.